# multiple index data update

Tags: r

I have data in this format and I load them in a data frame Lines.

```
number            value   day  
  2                 2       21/3/2010 00:01:00
  2                 3       21/3/2010 00:02:00
  2                 4       21/3/2010 00:03:00
  3                 2       21/3/2010 00:01:00
  3                 3       21/3/2010 00:02:00
  3                 5       21/3/2010 00:03:00
  3                 4       21/3/2010 00:04:00
  4                 4       21/3/2010 00:01:00
  4                 4       21/3/2010 00:02:00
  4                 4       21/3/2010 00:03:00
  4                 4       21/3/2010 00:04:00

 dm <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

I try the data based on number column. x-axis has the day and y-axis the column values and from the column number I could take groups of data based on the number (3 different plots).

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Here will get you what I think you want, except for the x-axis labels. Should generalize to more than three plots

```
dm <- data.frame(number=c(2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4),
        value=c(2,3,4,2,3,5,4,4,4,4,4),
        day=c("21/3/2010 00:01:00",
              "21/3/2010 00:02:00",
              "21/3/2010 00:03:00",
              "21/3/2010 00:01:00",
              "21/3/2010 00:02:00",
              "21/3/2010 00:03:00",
              "21/3/2010 00:04:00",
              "21/3/2010 00:01:00",
              "21/3/2010 00:02:00",
              "21/3/2010 00:03:00",
              "21/3/2010 00:04:00"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
layout(matrix(1:length(unique(dm$number)),nrow=1, ncol=length(unique(dm$number))))
z <- sapply(unique(dm$number), FUN=function(x) 
    plot(dm$value[dm$number==x],as.factor(dm$day[dm$number==x]), ylab="Value", xaxt="n", xlab="Day", main=paste0("Day ",x), type="l") )
rm(z)
```

[image: plot]